# Outgoing connections from server with multiple IPs

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-networking, ubuntu-16.04

We have a server with both a /31 and a /24 in different /8s statically routed to it.
We have a gateway in the same /24 as the /31.

Incoming connections to IPs in the /24 work as expected, but we are unable to initiate outgoing connections.
Our "gold-standard" test is (using an IP to avoid dns issues at this point):

```sh
curl --interface SOME_IP_IN_THE_24 -v -H 'Host: httpbin.org' 34.230.136.58/ip
```

We're using Ubuntu 16.04, and we've configured eno1 with one of the /31, eno1:1 with the other /31, and eno1:2 with one of the IPs from the /24.
When we run the command above, we still get the IP for eno1.

Comment: Provide the outputs of commands `ip -4 a` and `ip -4 r`, and `iptables-save -c`, if you can.

Comment: @AntonDanilov iptables only has rules on the INPUT chain, and a MASQUERADE rule on the POSTROUTING chain of the nat table, but otherwise empty.

This is the result of `ip route` using RFC 5737 IPs in place of real ones:

```
default via 192.0.2.1 dev eno1 onlink 
203.0.113.0/24 dev eno1  proto kernel  scope link  src 203.0.113.198 
192.0.2.0/24 dev eno1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.0.2.198 
```

We're able to get incoming traffic, but outgoing it's getting mangled to use the wrong IP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Troubleshooting

- Check the routing with `ip route get <dst> from <SOME_IP_IN_THE_24>` command. Fix it if the command has returned unexpected route.
- Check the firewall with `iptables-save -c`. The source address can be overridden by NAT rules.

#### The answer

Your issue caused by the MASQUERADE rule. Any source address is rewritten to an ip address, which you see in the source attribute of route, that has been got by the `ip route get <dst>` command. You can sure in that with using of the `tcpdump` and `conntrack -E` commands. Likely also you see increment of this rule counters.

Simple way to avoid this behavior is just insert ACCEPT rules at the top of the `nat/PREROUTING` chain. Better way to change the firewall rule set is usage of `iptables-save`/`iptables-apply` commands. Your `nat/PREROUTING` chain should look like (`iptables-save -t nat`):

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.2 on Thu Jul  4 19:05:27 2019
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING --src <LOCAL-IP-1> -j ACCEPT
-A POSTROUTING --src <LOCAL-IP-2> -j ACCEPT
...
-A POSTROUTING --src <LOCAL-IP-N> -j ACCEPT
-A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Jul  4 19:05:27 2019
```

Comment: we brought in a networking expert who fixed the issue for us. The solution was to add a new routing table for the /24 and configure all the IPs for the same interface (not using virtual interfaces). The masquerade rule was also causing issues (it was added automatically by docker) and removing it worked perfectly, but broke outgoing connections from docker, so we added rules as you suggested.

Thank you!